# App hangs when trying to redirect STDERR to capture logs on iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, mobile, stderr

I'm using the following code to capture the log output of the device to be able to send it with support tickets and in 200 line chunks to the server in my iOS app.

```
// This redirects stderr to pipe and handles it back in the main thread
-(void)redirectStandardErrorToAsyncMainDispatcher
{
    // Save reference to strerr
    stdoutDescriptor = dup(fileno(stderr));

    // Redirect stderr to pipe
    dup2([[self.logPipe fileHandleForWriting] fileDescriptor], fileno(stderr));

    // Add observer for pipe
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self selector: @selector(handleNotification:) name: NSFileHandleReadCompletionNotification object: self.logPipeHandleForReading] ;

    // Read pipe in background and notify
    [self.logPipeHandleForReading readInBackgroundAndNotify] ;
}
```

Which redirects it to this method:

```
-(void)handleNotification:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    // Read pipe in background and notify
    [self.logPipeHandleForReading readInBackgroundAndNotify] ;

    // Get the original string sent to stderr
    NSString *stdOutString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: [[notification userInfo] objectForKey: NSFileHandleNotificationDataItem] encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding] ;

    // Forward string to stdout
    [stdOutString writeToFile:@"/dev/stdout" atomically:NO encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

    // Add string to log pool
    [self addStringToLogPool:stdOutString];
}
```

Which forwards it stdout, and then to this method which stores it in the log pools and handles cleaning them or sending them to the server, etc.

```
-(void)addStringToLogPool:(NSString*)stringToAdd
{
    // If log pool is enabled
    if (self.ticketLogPool &&
        self.logTrackingLogPool)
    {
        // Add string to log pool
        [self.ticketLogPool addObject:stringToAdd];
        [self.logTrackingLogPool addObject:stringToAdd];

        // If we have reached the maximum log pool size
        if (self.logTrackingLogPool.count > self.maximumLogPoolSize)
        {
            // If log tracking is enabled
            if (self.isLogTrackingEnabled)
            {
                // Send log pool content to server
                [self sendLogPoolContentToServer:self.logTrackingLogPool];

                // Clean log pool
                [self emptyLogPoolContent:self.logTrackingLogPool];

                // Increase log identifier
                self.logTransmissionNumber = [NSNumber numberWithLong:[self.logTransmissionNumber longValue] + 1];
            }
            // Otherwise, clean last row in queue
            else
            {
                [self.logTrackingLogPool removeObject:[self.logTrackingLogPool objectAtIndex:0]];
            }
        }

        // If we have reached the maximum log pool size
        if (self.ticketLogPool.count > self.maximumLogPoolSize)
        {
            [self.ticketLogPool removeObject:[self.ticketLogPool objectAtIndex:0]];
        }
    }
}
```

All seems to be in working order. The only problem is when I get spammed with a lot of log messages in a short time, I stop getting them at all and the app freezes. Not a crash or anything, just freezes. Its like the pipe is flooded with messages before I can clear it to read it in the background.

What can be done to overcome this?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you in control of the code writing to `stderr`?

Comment: Well technically yes but I do have the framework writing to that as well (Cocos2D).

Comment: I would recommend simplifying this by doing all logging via your own functions.  You can make cocos2d use your methods by modifying the `CCLOG()` macro within one of their header files.  I have done this in the past (but don't bother now as it hasn't ever produced something I'm interested in within production).  Besides I just use Crashlytics to write logging information along with any crash logs.